# Qt 5 парсинг JSON

Tags: json, qt5, qt, c++

Имею QByteArray, содержащий следующий JSON:

```
{
    "response": {
        "count": 2,
        "items": [
            {"name": "somename", "key": 1"},
            {"name": "somename", "key": 1"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Нужно пропарсить и получить необходимые данные:

```
  QJsonDocument itemDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(answer);
  QJsonObject itemObject = itemDoc.object();

  qDebug() << itemObject;

  QJsonArray itemArray = itemObject["response"].toArray();
  qDebug() << itemArray;
```

Первый дебаг выводит содержание всего `QByteArray`, записанное в `itemObject`, второй дебаг не выводит ничего.

Подскажите, может, нужно парсить иначе или почему этот способ не работает?

Answer (score 7):

Может проблема из-за невнимательности. `response` у Вас это не `Array`, а `Object`. Потому

```
itemObject["response"].toArray()
```

писать неверно!